# External monitor LG 24mk600m-b not recognized, on Dell XPS13-9343 and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, dell, intel-graphics, external-monitor

While on Windows 10 the second monitor works smoothly, throught the DisplayLink adapter and HDMI cable, on Ubuntu 20.04 the monitor is not recognized.

From `inxi -Fx`:

```
System:    Host: ebergam Kernel: 5.8.0-43-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: XPS 13 9343 v: N/A serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: Dell model: 0310JH v: A00 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: Dell v: A20 date: 06/06/2019 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 2.5 Wh condition: 10.4/52.7 Wh (20%) model: SMP DELL 0N7T653 status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-5500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Broadwell rev: 4 L2 cache: 4096 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 19156 
           Speed: 798 MHz min/max: 500/3000 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 927 2: 880 3: 843 4: 928 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 5500 vendor: Dell driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 driver: i915 resolution: 3200x1800~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.6 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Broadwell-U Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 
           Device-2: Intel Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio vendor: Dell driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Device-3: DisplayLink type: USB driver: cdc_ncm,snd-usb-audio bus ID: 3-2.1:5 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-43-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Dell driver: wl v: kernel 
           port: f040 bus ID: 02:00.0 
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: c4:8e:8f:f6:a1:e7 
           IF-ID-1: enx9cebe82ffd50 state: down mac: 9c:eb:e8:2f:fd:50 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 167.71 GiB (70.3%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD PM851 M.2 2280 256GB size: 238.47 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 30.43 GiB used: 11.73 GiB (38.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 52.0 C mobo: 40.0 C sodimm: 42.0 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 0 
Info:      Processes: 279 Uptime: 2h 14m Memory: 7.68 GiB used: 3.68 GiB (47.9%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

And `xrandr --displaymonitors`:

```
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP-1 3200/294x1800/165+0+0  eDP-1
```

It seems like the monitor is not recognized. I am pretty sure that it's not the DiplayLink adapter's fault (the sound settings pass to HDMI when I connect, and I can plug USB devices from there). Any idea what I might be missing in order to use the LG monitor as a second screen?

thank you